# Confusion with Spring Security in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm working with Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE, Spring Security 4.1.3.RELEASE, and Java 8.

For the security configuration I have the following class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/assets/**", "/logout", "/login");
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .sessionManagement()  //  1
                    .sessionFixation() // 2
                    .migrateSession() // 3
                    .maximumSessions(1) // 4
                    .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true).expiredUrl("/login").and() // 5
                    .invalidSessionUrl("/login") // 6
                    .and() // 7
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/app/**").authenticated()
                    .antMatchers("/about").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/auth").permitAll()
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/app/index", true)
                    .failureUrl("/login?error")
                    .usernameParameter("uid")
                    .passwordParameter("pwd").and()
                .logout()
                    .permitAll()
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .logoutUrl("/logout").permitAll()
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll()
                    .clearAuthentication(true).and()
                .exceptionHandling().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .headers().frameOptions().disable()
                .cacheControl().and();
    }
}
```

When try access to "**/about**" (permit all everyone), redirects me to "**/login**".  I try it a second time and now it allows me to access "**/about**".

I have changed the authorization order of requests in the configuration class but don't works. When I delete the lines of sessionManagement (1 to 7), everything works normally.

Do I need any extra configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are testing this, did you clear your browser's cookie with regard to your testing site?  The session management filter sets a jsessionid cookie, which gets sent back.  Your browser has no idea that you reset your server, so thinks the cookie is just fine, and you send back an invalid session.

You may want to take a look at your session creation policies to see whether or not it suits your purpose.

Comment: Thanks! I just add `sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)` and it works!